# Canon MF730 all-in-one scanner not found. Printer was installed and works completely

Tags: drivers, scanner, canon

Have installed the MF730/733 printer on IP address (network printer). works fine. Scanner is not found using sane or xsane. Installed xsane and performed update.  Modified net.conf and saned.conf files for ip address. What do I do next?

Comment: The MF733 printer install file is from Canon , seems to be only the printer.

Comment: re-install after software update error. Now scan is found and works using xsane & simplescan.